# why does cv2.Sobel function returns a black and white image instead of grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

code -

```
    frame=cv2.imread('ball2.jpg',0)
    frame_blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(7,7),0)
    sobelx=cv2.Sobel(frame_blur,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,dst=None,ksize=5)
    sobely=cv2.Sobel(frame_blur,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,dst=None,ksize=5)
    lap=cv2.Laplacian(frame_blur,cv2.CV_64F)
    
   
    cv2.imshow('sobelx',sobelx)
    cv2.imshow('sobely',sobely)
    cv2.imshow('laplecian',lap)
```

why does cv2.solber returns a black and white image instead of grayscale and what is the threshold the cv2.solber function uses after finding the gradient in the image.

same thing happens with the cv2.laplecian function ^^^

one more question why do we normalise the image after applying solber kernel . i understand that  sometimes we get a negative value after applying the solder kernel but doesn't opencv converts the negative no. to positive automatically
for eg:  -1 to 255 , -2 to 244

Comment: What is your input image? Please show more code.

Comment: @fmw42 check now

Comment: You need to scale the images to the [0,1] range for display. They probably look like black and white because they exceed that range by a large amount.

Comment: Where is the input image? Please post so that others can use to test your code. Post to some free hosting service and put the URL here. But `@Cris Luengo` probably has identified your issue. Or you could normalize the output to bias and scale to 0 to 255 and convert to uint8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to create the sobel and normalize for saving in Python/OpenCV. Method 1: stretch min and max values to range -255 to 255, then clip negative values so range is 0 to 255.  Method 2: stretch min and max values to range 0 to 255 (so zero in Sobel becomes mid gray).

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as exposure

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)

# apply sobel x derivative
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(blur,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
      
# normalize to range -1 to 1
sobelx_norm1a = exposure.rescale_intensity(sobelx, in_range='image', out_range=(-1,1))

# normalize to range -255 to 255 and clip negatives 
sobelx_norm1b = exposure.rescale_intensity(sobelx, in_range='image', out_range=(-255,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# normalize to range 0 to 255
sobelx_norm8 = exposure.rescale_intensity(sobelx, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('barn_sobel_norm1b.jpg', sobelx_norm1b)
cv2.imwrite('barn_sobel_norm8.jpg', sobelx_norm8)

# show results
cv2.imshow('sobelx_norm1a', sobelx_norm1a)  
cv2.imshow('sobelx_norm1b', sobelx_norm1b)  
cv2.imshow('sobelx_norm8', sobelx_norm8)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result 1:

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

I suspect you want the second method. But are getting the first method when you use float values that get negative values clipped as in my displayed result 1a.

Comment: do you mind explaining  the normalisation of method 2 , after normalisation how does '0' becomes mid gray ?

Comment: It does not guarantee that 0 goes to mid gray, only near that. If your derivatives in float values are min=-max, then then 0 would go to mid gray, because we are stretching min to 0 and max to 255. So 0 in derivative in approximate range -1 to +1 (where min=-max) would scale so that 0 in that range would go to mid gray. In exposure.rescale_intensity(), the option in_range='image' means find the min and max values of the input. Then it scales to out_range=(0,255)